# What does "really big int" mean in terms of time complexity and basic arithmetic operations

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I learnt that basic arithmetic operations are executed in constant time `O(1)` unless operands are "really big". So I tried this expecting `via_str_method` will execute faster when some boundary is reached:

```
import time
import math

start_time = time.time()


class OddNumbers:

    ODD_ONES = ["1", "3", "5", "7", "9"]

    def __init__(self, n):
        assert type(n) == int
        self.n = n
        self.str_n = str(n)

    def via_str_method(self):
        return True if self.str_n[-1] in self.ODD_ONES else False

    def via_mod_method(self):
        return True if self.n % 2 != 0 else False


n = int(math.pow(2, 1023))
odd_one = OddNumbers(n)

if odd_one.via_str_method():
    print("Number is ODD")
else:
    print("Number is EVEN")

str_end_time = time.time()
print(f"STR method time: {str_end_time - start_time}")

if odd_one.via_mod_method():
    print("Number is ODD")
else:
    print("Number is EVEN")

print(f"MOD method time: {time.time() - str_end_time}")
```

But even with `2**1023` (which I thought is "big enough"), both methods still executes in constant time.
I am wondering if someone could explain to me what is considered "really big int" and how to generate one and use it in code.

Comment: What are the last 7 lines repeated?

Comment: sorry, copy error, i edited. Still the same behaviour

Comment: Which output of this program do you get and what did you expect to get instead?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I get that both methods execute in `0.0s`. Since I used `2**1023` I expected that `via_mod_method` will not execute in constant time

Comment: If the output is "0.0s" you are not able to distinguish whether the time is 10 nanoseconds or 10 microseconds. You need to output more digits to actually be able to see a difference, if there is one.

Comment: Your operation doesn't need look at anything other than the last digit to determine the return value. The inputs may not have constant size, but the work necessary is constant.

Comment: The key here is that `str.__getitem__` can access the last digit in constant time, because the underlying storage supports random access, rather than requiring you to iterate over all the digits in O(n) time.

Comment: And `self.n % 2` can probably also be calculated in constant time because it only needs too look up the least significant bit of the number.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I understand but `time.time()` should be capable to show enough digits if required so I concluded `0.0` means constant time. Am I wrong?

Comment: The time cannot be *exactly* zero, so this must be an approximate value. Also even if it took 1000 seconds it could still be *constant*. Whether something is fast or slow is not directly related to whether it takes constant time or not.

Comment: Last two comments explains a lot. I was not aware of random access and looking at least significant bit. I thought `%` will do some kind of division, hence `2**1023` will take more time to calculate.
@mkrieger1 I am aware it can not be exactly zero, is there some module which is more sensitive?

Comment: @mkrieger1 By constant time I meant time for basic operation to be executed, like arithmetic operation, logic check, variable assignment, etc. Maybe I did not use a correct term

Comment: You get 0 coz the time taken was exremely less (maybe pico seconds or less). Secondly if an algorithm takes 10 minutes to execute it can still be considered constant if it continues to take 10 minutes for every possible input i.e. constant time for all types of inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first method you take a char from `self.str_n` using index. Index accessing is constant time. Next you check if it's in the list `ODD_ONES`. Searching a list is linear time, however the `ODD_ONES` is of fixed length irrespective of `n`. Hence that's also constant time.

In the second method you check for divisibility by 2. No matter how big the number is, the digit in units place is what determines the divisibility. Hence again this is constant time.

The people behind Python (and any other mainstream language) are really smart people ;)

Comment: All you stated explain why execution time does not change(go up). I was not aware that `%` works like that, so I learnt something new. I agree they are ;) I have additional question, every book (source) that I looked state that these operations are not constant for "very big numbers", what is considered a very big number, when obviously `2**1023` is not?

Comment: I'm not sure about the threshold for "very big numbers". 2**1023 is probably considered as one. However to see the execution time variation you need to perform really complex operations. Like machine learning stuff where summations are calculated repeatedly. With the basic operations like +,- etc. the variation (which theoretically exists) is too small to be perceivable.